# Ionic React cannot use flexbox in IonItem or load external .css

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-native

**Problem 1** 
I'm trying to style a component in order to put the 2 labels in column using this code

```
<IonContent>
        <IonList>
          {
            articles.map((article: any) => {
              return <IonItem
                style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%', width:'100%' }}
                key={article.Title}
                onClick={() => browser.create(article.Link)}>
                <IonLabel style={{ fontSize: 14 }} >{article.Title}</IonLabel>
                <IonLabel style={{ fontSize: 11 }}>{article.Magazine}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
            })
          }

        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
```

The labels correctly get the new `fontSize`, but the `IonItem` does not change the direction in which the 2 are displayed. 
Am I missing something??

**Problem 2** 
I decided to go with in-line styling because I could not load the `.css` part.
First I import the code in `Home.tsx`

```
import './Home.css';
```

which on the other hand contains the following code (`Home.css`):

```
.title {
    font-size: 12;
}
```

and then I use it

```
<IonLabel class="title">{article.Title}</IonLabel>
```

But it does not work. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be the case `<IonLabel className="title">{article.Title}</IonLabel>`

Answer (score 0):

dont wrap it in an `ion-item` and the css should work... If you want to use the `ion-item` then you will need to override the class `.input-wrapper`

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "100%",
  }}
  key={article.Title}
>
  <div style={{ fontSize: 14, flex: 1 }}>{article.Title}</div>
  <div style={{ fontSize: 11, flex: 1 }}>{article.Magazine}</div>
</div>
```